# Unable to get defined path in 'source' type on AIX node

Tags: puppet, aix, path, source

I am trying to create a set of users on my AIX node and trying to get 
their authorized_keys which are already hosted on my server with name 
like, 'myuser_id_dsa.pub'. Currently i am managing 2 nodes (1. SLES  2. AIX). I defined the 'source' file paths in 2 separate contexts in fileserver.conf;

[AIX]
    path myfiles/users/ssh/
    allow *.another.mydomain.com
[SLES]
       path myfiles/users/keys/ssh/
    allow *.mydomain.com

but when I run puppet then it ended successfully on my SLES node but 
encountered failure on AIX; with following err;

/* Could not describe /AIX/myuser_id_rsa.pub: Fileserver module 'AIX' 
not mounted*/

in my code i have defined the 'source' with $filserver variable as:

case $operatingsystem {
        "AIX": { $fileserver = "AIX" }
        default: { $fileserver = "SLES" }
    }

file { "${home}/${username}/.ssh/authorized_keys":
    source => "puppet:///$fileserver/${username}_is_dsa.pub",
    ...
    ...
}

why AIX is not able to get the source path from my fileserver.conf while 
SLES is running absolutely fine? and how can I do it? I have to run 
similar configuration across different servers so I can only deal it 
with case statement.

looking forward for your help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the reason in this case may be that you have an extra '/' in the source definition, which according to docs must conform to:

```
puppet://server/path
```

the triple '/' tells puppet to use the puppetmaster or default server, which in your case triggers a search for

```
/AIX/username_is_dsa.pub
```

However the puppet docs are confusing to me, and I don't know if the client or server is looking for a /AIX mountpoint...

Anyway try without the 3-'/'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what it's not working, but I would suggest using a single path exposed by the fileserver module, and just putting everything inside that.

One possibility could be a module named `AIX` shadowing the fileserver mount.